# group homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functions

Given: $ \varphi : ( S_4, \circ) ~~~\rightarrow ~~~(\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}),$ $~~~~~~~~~$ $\sigma \longmapsto [\sigma(1)]$

Is this function a group homomorphism?

My idea is, to calculate some values, but i don't know how to calculate $[\sigma(1)]$

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to calculate it? Do you know how it is defined?

Comment: If $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ then $\sigma(1)=3$, $\sigma(3)=2$ and $\sigma(2)=1$.

Comment: but i have to calculate $[\sigma(1)]$ not $\sigma(1)$

Comment: Indeed, and do you know how that is defined?

Comment: The equivalence relation is defined as $[a]=\{b \in X | a\

Comment: That is not a valid set construction, and it it not how that equivalence class is usually defined.

Comment: $ \pi: G \rightarrow G/U : x:\longmapsto[x]$ is a morphism with  $core (\pi) = U$

Comment: I am trying to get you to look up the definition of $[x]$ in this very specific context. Without knowing that definition, there is of course no way for you to do this exercise.

Comment: $[x] = x * U := \{x*u|  \in  U\}$

Answer (score 0):

To go from $\sigma(1)$ to $[\sigma(1)]$, you must reduce modulo $4$ (this is the image of the homomorphism you're trying to construct).

Now that you know how to compute $[\sigma(1)]$, you need to decide if this map is a homomorphism. That is, for all $\sigma,\tau\in S_4$, we need
$$ [(\tau\circ\sigma)(1)] = [\tau(1)\cdot \sigma(1)].$$

A hint if you're still unsure: try working this out with transpositions (cycles of length 2). If $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, then it will work out with transpositions, and maybe it will lead to a proof.